# NaN-Error at d3js error bars

Tags: d3.js, nan, pathelement

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bvkkt08k/1/) is the important part of my code. For some reasons, there is a problem with the "errorBars2". It always returns this error:

`Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M40.5,NaNL40.5,NaNZ"`

I spent now hours on searching for the mistake but I can't find it! Could somebody explain me what's the problem with the "errorBars2"?

Comment: Looks like errorBarArea2 has some miscalculations. as you can see  you get "NaNL40.5,NaNZ"

Comment: Yes, but where is the miscalculation? Or what is wrong? I really can't find it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In errorBarArea2 you have written for

```
.y0(function (d) {
        return y0(+d.top_after + +d.moe3);
    })
```

but in the JSON structure it is not available change it to `+d.moe3_after`

and you have written

```
.y1(function (d) {
return y0(+d.low_after - +d.moe4);
})
```

but in the JSON structure it is not available change it to `+d.moe4_after`

So the final code is

```
var errorBarArea2 = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function (d) {
        return x3(d.name) +x3.rangeBand()/2;
    })
    .y0(function (d) {
        return y0(+d.top_after + +d.moe3_after);
    })
    .y1(function (d) {
        return y0(+d.low_after - +d.moe4_after);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if this works.

```
var errorBarArea2 = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function (d) {
        return x3(d.name) +x3.rangeBand()/2;
    })
    .y0(function (d) {
        return y2(d.top_after + +d.moe3);
    })
    .y1(function (d) {
        return y2(d.low_after - +d.moe4);
    })
```